# What's an appropriate body font to couple with Bebas Neue

Tags: fonts

I'm in the process of redesigning my website, and I've selected Bebas Neue as a font for my logo and major features (navigation etc), but due to its blocky nature and the fact that it's 100% capitals, it's not really good to use as body copy.

[Here's a link to Bebas](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/bebas-neue)

I guess I just need to find something that would work well with it, but fonts aren't really my strong point. Can you lend a hand?

Answer (score 2):

The "golden rule" of font combinations is to pick fonts which give contrast. Since Bebas is a sans-serif font you should consider picking a **serif font**.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll look into it and see what's feels right.

Comment: Font pairings can also be contrasted using [typographic color](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typography#Color) and other visual qualities. However, the mood of the typefaces should be compatible with one another.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm using either [Open Sans](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans), or [Lato](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Lato) as my body fonts at the moment - works pretty well with most fonts.

But then again Open Sans is on the border line of being over used...

Answer (score 0):

Give Source Sans a try. Very similar structure. You may find you don't need Bebas at all.